# Hover a DIV also Effects Link Inside DIV

Tags: css, html, hover

I have the following CSS:

```
.contact{
  padding:1rem;
  background:#023B6C;
  padding:1rem;
  position:fixed;
  right:-20px;
  top:27%;
  z-index:99;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  transition:all .5 ease;
}

.contact a{
  font-size:1.2rem;
  color:#fff;
  transition:all .5 ease;
}

.contact a:hover{
  color:#E5E5E5;
  font-size:1.25rem;
}

.contact:hover{
  padding:1.2rem;
}
```

that controls the following HTML:

```
<div class="contact">
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

What this is doing is upon hovering over the div the div slightly expands and the text also expands. However, if a person doesn't hover directly over the text the text doesn't change, just the div.

How do I modify the code so the link inside the divs changes when the div is hovered but the text is not? I tried putting all of the code inside the `.contact:hover` but that didn't work as the link was styled by the default styles of my css.

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AwGca/1/) of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it from right to left...

Any, a - inside of .content that is on hover...

so

(from right to left)

```
.contact:hover  a {

}
```

But, I would make the whole thing an anchor. make it block and style the whole thing on hover.

Comment: Makes sense and I decided to follow your advice and just remove the div and make the CSS style the anchor.

Comment: Yeah, with fingers, and tapping etc - you want the biggest area for anchors as you can. Plus it would be really frustrating if you were trying to click the banner - and it wasn't working.